# Error creating index on DynamoDB table: AttributeDefinitions is not specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, command-line-interface, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to add a global secondary index to an existing DynamoDB table using the AWS command line interface.

As per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/update-table.html), I'm using this update-table command:

```
aws dynamodb update-table --table-name messages --global-secondary-index-updates file://input.json
```

and my input.json file has the definition of the index:

```
[
  {
    "Create": {
      "IndexName": "FeedIndex",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "feed",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "status",
          "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "INCLUDE",
        "NonKeyAttributes": ["message"]
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
      }
    }
  }
]
```

When I run the command, I get this error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateTable operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: AttributeDefinitions is not specified for index: FeedIndex
```

Why would I get this error? It seems to me from the documentation that I've specified all I need to for adding the index. AttributeDefinitions gets specified when creating a table initially; I would have thought that these definitions would not be needed for adding an index to an existing table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `attribute-definitions` was missed. You need to define the attributes that are part of `KeySchema`.

```
aws dynamodb update-table --table-name messages --attribute-definitions AttributeName=feed,AttributeType=S AttributeName=status,AttributeType=S --global-secondary-index-updates file://input.json
```

Comment: I have a similar question. I have created a table with Primary Partition Key as "attribute1".  After that I am trying to create an index on this table on a column "attribute2" only. Is this allowed? I am getting an error "ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: AttributeDefinitions is not specified for index"

Comment: index can only be created on pre-defined attributes, in your case attribute2 is not defined